# Trying to Upload iOS App, Can't Archive

Tags: ios, xcode, upload, archive

I made an app and am trying to upload it to iTunes Connect. I have a certificate installed, development certificate and distribution certificate...see picture..

[image]

[image]

[image]
...But, somehow, when I am trying to archive the app in Xcode to binary, it reports an error:

[image]
All my certificates are valid, but it's still complaining about distribution certificates,

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't appear to have a distribution profile (only a developer profile -- in organizer).  You appear to have a distribution certificate, but no profile.  You must create a distribution profile for your app.  You can do this in the portal.

Answer (score 0):

Did you generate the certificate on your own Mac? The certificate must match a private key in the keychain. If not, revoke the existing certificate and create a new one. You will have to perform the signing from Apple again.